# How to create Multi-Level Game with Cocos2D(iOS)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

1. I want to know how to create multi-level games with cocos2d.
2. I knew that big developers like Angry Birds, Cut the Rope have their own level-editor, but how does other people create multi-level games?

**Question:** How I can create/build levels, is there any kinds of builders? Or you need to create class for each level?

Comment: You should create class describing the level and then load the map from file(like XML, or just write your own format and create map editor for it). There's also available generic map editors, depending on what type of game you're writing.

Comment: @Ruuhkis I'm will be writing Arcade(View from the side). So I need some kind of good level editor. If I would write RPG or Strategy I could use TileMap.

Comment: There's CocosBuilder to help with user interfaces.  The page also says it can help with level design.  http://cocosbuilder.com/

Comment: @DanyalAytekin Yeah, I know about this tool. But is it a good solution for bulding levels with the scrolling background?

Comment: @DanyalAytekin I found solution, by creating a custom CCLayer, for example set height of 320(iPhone) and width for example 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using Levelhelper for an upcoming game..
It really helps and heavily reduces the development time.
Instead of writing your own parser, and trail-and-error xml files, you get a nice editor with lots of features. I would recommend it, definitely if you haven't endless levels.

Comment: I will have levels with the scrolling background. So can I use LevelEditor for this purposes?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Levelhelper uses parallaxes for this which works fine

Comment: Thanks, did you used before CocosBuilder? They are saying that you can build levels with it as well. I will try it out today. Just one big advantage of it, is that it's absolutely free. But it is really cool tool. I wish I could get a trial of LevelHelper, just to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am using single Scene/Layer and dynamically loading level data from XML (map images, collision, enemy formation definition, ...). It depends on your requirements. Are your maps endless? Find more info about my solution on http://www.iuridium.com/?page_id=2. Also, this may help you: http://www.levelhelper.org.

Comment: No, they are not. I knew about LevelHelper. What you think about it? Did you used it before?

Comment: How did you create levels and pack them on XML File?